# .NET CultureInfo for Cuba?

Tags: .net, globalization, cultureinfo

I just noticed that the .NET Framework [doesn't include Cuba in the CultureInfo class (format xx-XX)](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/globalization/demos/CultureInfo.aspx). What is the best practice on this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think best practice is [to create a Custom CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469.aspx).

Or you could use `new CultureInfo("es")`.

Answer (score 4):

Since there isn't a specific culture for Cuba, I would stick with simply using `es` (since it is a Spanish speaking country).